# how to use select in generating expression in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables.

1. response(id,quiz_id,question_id,student_id,mark)
2. total_mark (id,quiz_id,student_id,total_mark)

i need to make total_mark as generated column where
total_mark= sum of marks in response where response.quiz_id=quiz_id and response.student_id=student_id. is it possible to achieve in mysql using generating expression.
i have tried this

```
    CREATE TABLE total_mark 
(id int,quiz_id int,student_id int, total_mark decimal(5,2)
 AS (select sum(response.mark) from response where
 response.student_id=student_pid and response.quiz_id=quiz_id ));

insert INTO total_mark  ('quiz_id','student_id') values ('1',2)
```

response table is like this
id,quiz_id,question_id,student_id,mark

```
1,1,1,2,2

2,1,2,2,2

3,1,3,2,0

4,1,4,2,1
```

but error at `select`
**when ever i update *table response* the *table total mark* need to be updated...**
is it possible to achive this any way..

Comment: Please read [13.1.20.8 CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) and, if question remains, [edit] your question.

Comment: I have gone through it before and i tried what is given in question. But error.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
CREATE TABLE total_mark  AS 
SELECT quiz_id,student_id ,sum(mark) as total_mark 
FROM response
GROUP BY student_id,quiz_id;
ALTER TABLE total_mark ADD  id INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD INDEX (id) ;
```

If you do not need the 'id' column in 'total_mark'  table ,you can skip the `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: Hello Sama Latifi thankyou for your answer. But there is a problem in solution that i required.
The column total_mark need to be updated when i update table response.
But the table total_,ark  is not updating when i edit the table response.

Answer (score 0):

I do think this is not possible with generated columns, but that it can be done using a TRIGGER.

```
-- Create TABLES
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS response;
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS total_mark;

CREATE TABLE response(id int, quiz_id int, question_id int, student_id int, mark int);
INSERT INTO response VALUES
    (1,1,1,2,2),
    (2,1,2,2,2),
    (3,1,3,2,0),
    (4,1,4,2,1);
   
CREATE TABLE total_mark 
(id int,quiz_id int,student_id int, total_mark decimal(5,2));

-- Create TRIGGER
-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ins_total_mark;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ins_total_mark BEFORE INSERT ON total_mark
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   SET new.total_mark=(select sum(response.mark) from response where
 response.student_id=new.student_id and response.quiz_id=new.quiz_id );
END;//
DELIMITER ;

-- Test to see what gets inserted
select sum(response.mark) from response where quiz_id=1 and student_id=2;

-- Test insert data that fires trigger
insert INTO total_mark  (`quiz_id`,`student_id`) values ('1',2);
select * from total_mark;
```

Comment: There is some problem.      
`SET new.total_mark=(select sum(response.mark) from response where
 response.student_id= **student_id** and response.quiz_id=**quiz_id**   );`      
total mark is shown as sum of all mark in response table.
it is not checking value of the student_id and quiz_id inserted in **table total_,mark**

Comment: I did change the trigger (I added 2 time a `new.`). I hope this solves your problem, because I am pretty unexperienced in writing triggers, you will have to investigate further if this is not correct 

Comment: Thanks.... it works... But in a different way than I expected.